# Why am i getting different values when i apply .value_counts() separately on the filters and if i apply it on the whole column?

Tags: python, pandas

filt = df['driver_gender'] == 'M'
df[filt].value_counts().sum()

OUTPUT: 2111

filt = df['driver_gender'] == 'F'
df[filt].value_counts().sum()

OUTPUT: 366

df['driver_gender'].value_counts()

OUTPUT: M = 45164,
F = 16310

Answer (score 0):

IIUC for count by mask need `sum`:

```
filt = df['driver_gender'] == 'M' 
filt.sum()
```

For me your solution working too, is possible some variables mismatch?

```
print ((df['driver_gender'] == 'M').sum())
print (df[df['driver_gender'] == 'M'].value_counts().sum())
```